# Cannot represent equality constraint as a custom constraint

Tags: haskell, typeclass, yesod

I have a function type declaration

```
f :: MonadHandler m => SqlPersistT m ()
```

Which I want to convert to

```
f :: MonadHandlerDB m => m ()
```

I try everything I can think of to define constraint MonadHandlerDB, but cannot get either it or function type declaration to compile, e.g.:

```
class (forall a . (MonadHandler m, m ~ SqlPersistT a)) => MonadHandlerDB m

class MonadHandlerDB m
instance MonadHandler a => MonadHandlerDB (SqlPersistT a)

type MonadHandlerDB m = forall a . (MonadHandler a, m ~ SqlPersistT a)

type MonadHandlerDB = forall a . (MonadHandler a => m ~ SqlPersistT a)

type MonadHandlerDB m = forall a . (MonadHandler a => m ~ SqlPersistT a)
```

One of the errors:

```
Couldn't match type `m' with `ReaderT backend0 m0
`m' is a rigid type variable bound by
the type signature for:
  f:: forall (m :: * -> *).
      MonadHandlerDB m =>
      m ()
```

SqlPersistT is defined as

```
type SqlPersistT = ReaderT SqlBackend
```

How do I express this constraint?

Comment: The second option without any equality constraints seems the most sensible to me, why didn't that work out? You might need `TypeSynonymInstances` or manually expand the synonym and use `FlexibleInstances`.

Comment: I get type mismatch for function body:
Couldn't match type 'm' with 'ReaderT backend0 m0'
 'm' is a rigid type variable bound by
   the type signature for:
     f :: forall (m :: * -> *).
          MonadHandlerDB m =>
          m ()
   at src\Util\NoFoundation\Currency\Esqueleto.hs:41:1-74
 Expected type: m ()
   Actual type: ReaderT backend0 m0 ()

Comment: @Noughtmare I have enabled a whole bunch of extensions, including `TypeSynonymInstances`. What do you mean by "manually expanding synonym"?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're actually trying to do. You might be asking how to create an abstraction, which @Noughtmare has described how to do. But that error message looks like what would happen if you tried to write a logically impossible conversion function based on that abstraction. Can you add in context about what you're actually trying to write that's resulting in such errors?

Comment: @Carl I am trying to create an "alias" for a set of constraints - in this case rather simple, but i have similar situation with more constraints. What I ultimately want is to have a single constraint to use for multiple function type declarations, instead of repeating many constraints for each function declaration. I am relying on constraints instead of just using a concrete type to avoid import cycle - just a way Yesod project is structured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this achieves what you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ReaderT (ReaderT))
import Database.Persist.Sql (SqlPersistT)
import Yesod.Core (MonadHandler)

f :: MonadHandlerDB m => m ()
f = undefined

class (MonadHandler (Sub m), m ~ SqlPersistT (Sub m)) => MonadHandlerDB m where
  type Sub m :: * -> *

instance MonadHandler m => MonadHandlerDB (SqlPersistT m) where
  type Sub (SqlPersistT m) = m
```

But note that I think this is really not very good to use in practice. It makes it seem as if the `m` is completely polymorphic, but, in fact, it can only ever be some monad inside `SqlPersistT`.

Constraints are powerful, but I think a constraint like this has a high potential to confuse its users.

Comment: I believe it is exactly what I wanted, thank you! I will consider your advice though, don't want to have bad practice in my code. This declaration looks kinda complicated for what it does, so it really might be a bad approach on my side.